# go to a directory, run a script, change directory, repeat

Tags: bash, unix

I know next to nothing about bash scripts. I have to run some scripts (created by other people) that I have to run from particular directories. Once the script stops running (1 hour). I change directories from the prompt, go to another directory and run another script (usually the same csh file but with different parameters). I have to do this 25 times. I was wondering if there was a way to create a "sh" file that could automate the process. That way I can gain some time by running it overnight.

```
#! /bin/bash

cd /dev/D/Folder1 

unzip file1.zip

$ALR_SH/someonesscript.csh -DIR $PWD -otherfilter blah1


cd /dev/D/Folder2

 unzip file2.zip

$ALR_SH/someonesscript.csh -DIR $PWD -otherfilter blah2

.
.
.

and so on.
```

Thanks and I'm sorry if this is too vague. I don't actually have access to the folder which stores the "csh" file that I am running so I don't know about its peculiarities and nor can I share it.

Comment: It the simplest, if you know in advance exactly the commands you want to execute and exactly the order in which you want to execute them then you can just list them all out, one per line, in a text file, put a shebang line at the top, and you're good to go.  Much like what you've posted.  Have you tried it?

Comment: Short answer yes! But, you need `#!/bin/bash` (no space). You also need to confirm that the change of directory was successful. (i.e. `cd /some/dir && { unzip file1.zip; $ALR_SH...; }` Also, look at `pushd` and `popd` to change to, and return to your original starting dir.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I didn't try it yet because I recall reading on the stacks that changing directories was complicated. I'll try it now.. well in 1 hour because I just ran a script.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Some of the earlier commands I ran from a bash file, which didn't involve changing directories, I had that space between ! and /bin. I thought that it ran correctly and my output looked good. Do I have to run it again? Thanks for the &&{..} suggestion. I will google pushd and popd. thanks.

Comment: The space in the shebang (`#!`) line is fine though mostly not used and not necessary. See http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/shebang/ for more details about it then you probably care to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Script languages are for doing exactly what it is you are trying to do. It can be as simple as just listing each command you need to execute, or you can take advantage of some of the shell capabilities to make your job easier. When you are running things "while you sleep" always make sure to setup a simple log file so you can find out what didn't go quite right while you slept:

```
#!/bin/bash

logfile=/path/to/log/file.txt       ## keep a simple logfile

cd /dev/D/Folder1 &>/dev/null && {  ## execute script on successful change into directory

    printf "%s - excuting someonesscript in %s\n" "$(date '+%b %e %T')" "$PWD" >> "$logfile"
    unzip file1.zip
    $ALR_SH/someonesscript.csh -DIR $PWD -otherfilter blah1 && \
    printf "%s - script in %s succeeded\n" "$(date '+%b %e %T')" "$PWD" >> "$logfile" || \
    printf "%s - script in %s FAILED\n" "$(date '+%b %e %T')" "$PWD" >> "$logfile"
}

...

and so on.
```

Or you can make use of simple arrays and loops to shorten the repetition (you can even put the list of directories in a separate text file if you wish). Shells are extremely capable of doing whatever is needed in the administration of a Linux system.

The following is just a simple example of making use of a common base directory and an array holding each subdirectory to change to and execute your script in. **Note:** always make sure you provide either an **absolute path** or a **correct relative path** when changing directories (I would recommend absolute paths until you are comfortable with skipping around using relative paths):

```
#!/bin/bash

logfile=/path/to/log/file.txt       ## keep a simple logfile
basedir=/dev/D                      ## common base directory name

dirarray=( Folder1                  ## array of foldernames to change to
           Folder2 )

for i in "${dirarray[@]}"; do       ## for each folder in dirarray

    if cd "${basedir}/${i}" &>/dev/null; then   ## if successful change to directory

        ## execute commands and log success/failure
        printf "%s - excuting someonesscript in %s\n" "$(date '+%b %e %T')" "$PWD" >> "$logfile"
        unzip file1.zip
        $ALR_SH/someonesscript.csh -DIR $PWD -otherfilter blah1 && \
        printf "%s - script in %s succeeded\n" "$(date '+%b %e %T')" "$PWD" >> "$logfile" || \
        printf "%s - script in %s FAILED\n" "$(date '+%b %e %T')" "$PWD" >> "$logfile" 

    else

        ## log failure to change into directory
        printf "%s - failed to change to directory '%s'\n" "$(date '+%b %e %T')" "$i" >> "$logfile"

    fi

done
```

In the morning, just check `/path/to/log/file.txt` to see how things went.

```
Jun 24 20:59:26 - excuting someonesscript in /home/david/scr/tmp/stack/dat/Folder1
Jun 24 20:59:59 - script in /home/david/scr/tmp/stack/dat/Folder1 succeeded
Jun 24 20:59:59 - failed to change to directory 'Folder2'
Jun 24 21:01:21 - excuting someonesscript in /home/david/scr/tmp/stack/dat/Folder3
Jun 24 21:01:21 - script in /home/david/scr/tmp/stack/dat/Folder3 succeeded
```

**Note:** all of the `$(date '+%b %e %T')` syntax is just to make your logfile look pretty. I.e.:

Comment: This is awesome!! Thank you! I will implement your instructions now and let you know tomorrow morning how it went.

Comment: Good luck. `bash` is a phenomenally capable script language. Not the fastest, but it is more than fast enough to do what you need to do. Spend time learning it, the string handling in particular [**String Manipulation**](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html) it will save you no end of time and greatly expand how you look at scripting.

Comment: I am getting an error with /dev/null. Actually for this task, the directory is /home/blah/blah so I just replaced &>/home/null (in your first script) and I am getting an error "operation not applicable"

Comment: You can remove the redirection entirely. It just hides the error message when there is no directory to change to. `&>/dev/null` Simply says take `stdout` and `stderr` (normal output, and error streams) and send them to the **bit bucket** (i.e. nowhere so they don't print). Just remove the `&>/dev/null` altogether and we will work on why it is failing for you later. `&>/dev/null` is just shorthand for the full `>/dev/null 2>&1` redirection command.

Comment: It's working now or doing something. I had a typo in the directory name. I ran it with the &>. I will report on this tomorrow morning. Thanks a lot.

Comment: it worked!! Thank you!! Now I will create one for the rest and hopefully I'll be a happy man tomorrow morning! :)

Comment: Excellent. Within a couple of months you can be a shell scripting wizard. Just remember to **test** and **double-check** and you will do fine.